# Exclude parts of .emacs when executing eval-buffer

Tags: init-file

If I modify my `.emacs` file I usually call `eval-buffer` to apply all changes to existing buffers without restarting emacs. Now I have the following lines to invoke `helm-mini` each time emacs starts:

```
(if (< (length command-line-args) 2) 
(setq initial-buffer-choice (car (helm-mini)))
)
```

The problem is that if I call `eval-buffer` it displays a helm mini buffer each time.

How can I make emacs exclude those lines when calling `eval-buffer` or alternatively, how can I change the code lines above such that the problem doesn't occur anymore?

Comment: Use `eval-region` instead and select the region to be evaluated.  Or, comment out what you don't want to be evaluated when calling `eval-buffer`.  Or, simply put in conditions to prevent certain portions of code from being evaluated -- e.g., `(defvar foo nil)` -- and set the variable to either `t` or `nil` -- `(if foo . . .)`.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate, but I don't have the time to look for it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call (helm-mini) after Emacs has started up, you can add it to `emacs-startup-hook` in your init file:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook #'helm-mini)
```

This way Emacs will run this function upon startup, but not upon re-evaluation of your init file.

Comment: What does the `#` do?

Comment: When `'foo` is compiled, it's fine if foo it not a function. When `#'foo` is compiled, Emacs will warn about foo not being a function.