# Execute command on every start except you load a file from commandline

Tags: start-up

To load `helm-mini` every-time when emacs starts, I use the following line in my .emacs file as suggested in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26402/2323

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook #'helm-mini)
```

This in particular avoids that `helm-mini` is loaded if I execute `eval-buffer` after changing my `.emacs`-file.

However there is another problem with it: If I start `emacs` from command line like `emacs myfile.tex`, emacs opens the file `myfile.tex` but also opens `helm-mini`. How can I make emacs not to load `helm-mini` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `command-line-args` contains the command line `("emacs")` when there are no arguments and `("emacs" "myfile.tex")` when you invoke it for myfile.tex. The simplest thing I can think of doing here is to check the length:

```
(when (< (length command-line-args) 2)
  (add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook #'helm-mini))
```